# get email address from username outlook java

Tags: java, email, outlook, jakarta-mail, exchangewebservices

I need to get the email address corresponding to a particular Username in outlook through JAVA. 
I have tried digging into the microsoft exchange webservices API, but couldnt find anything useful. The only faint hope i had was with the , 
resolveNames() method, but that proved to be a dead end. 
Does anyone have an idea on how to go about it?

what i basically need is this :

username : "abcxqz"

when we do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> on outlook, it gives the corresponding contact or email address.

i need to simulate the same functionality in code( JAVA ) .
Any pointers or links to API's that could help me achieve this would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: select mailaddress where username like ' + input + '
store your addressbook in a list, and search based on the username.

Comment: hey, dont have the option or luxury of storing the complete directory , need to get it on the fly .

Comment: impossible. if outlook was only possible with one single domain, then it would be doable, but since that's not the case ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void getEmailId() throws Exception {
    init();
    NameResolutionCollection nameResults = exchangeService.resolveName("royran");
    Map<String, String> results = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    for (NameResolution name : nameResults) {
        String contactName = name.getMailbox().getName();
        String emailAddress = name.getMailbox().getAddress();
        results.put(contactName, emailAddress);
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : results.entrySet())
    { 
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
    } 
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

What code exactly do you use? Could you be more specific?

You can use the [ExchangeService.ResolveName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.resolvename(v=exchg.80).aspx) EWS Managed API method or the [ResolveNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa565329(v=exchg.150).aspx) EWS operation to return a list of potential matches for a selection of text, such as part of a last name. The returned items can be public user mailboxes, distribution groups, and contacts.

```
// Resolve the ambiguous name "dan".
NameResolutionCollection resolvedNames = service.ResolveName("dan");
// Output the list of candidates.
foreach (NameResolution nameRes in resolvedNames)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Contact name: " + nameRes.Mailbox.Name);
   Console.WriteLine("Contact e-mail address: " + nameRes.Mailbox.Address);
   Console.WriteLine("Mailbox type: " + nameRes.Mailbox.MailboxType);
}
```

See [How to: Resolve ambiguous names by using EWS in Exchange 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn645423(v=exchg.150).aspx) for more information.

Comment: i basically have a directory of contacts maintained on the company server, i am currently sending emails using a static address, but i'd want the user to just enter the username, and then i could get the email id, as what happens, when we enter the username in the "to" field and hit Ctrl + K, the email id gets populated. I Tried using resolveNames earlier as well, but to my understanding it works in a GREP sort of way, not fetching the single email id requested, because we have a one-to-one mapping of emailId's and usernames.